# Windows phone 7 localization miss <SupportedCultures> element

Tags: windows-phone-7, localization, windows-phone-7.1

I am building a localized wp7 application by following the MSDN article "How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone". [here is the link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff637520%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

The article says that I need to add each addintional language in `<SupportedCultures>` element in my project.csproj file. But I couldn't find any `<SupportedCultures>` element in the project.csproj file. Can anyone tell where I can put the `<SupportedCultures>` element. Thanks.

Here is the code in project.csproj file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="GUID">
        <SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor>
          <FullDeploy>False</FullDeploy>
        </SilverlightMobileCSProjectFlavor>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project file should have **a lot more** than just that!

But here is what you requested, all you have to do is merge your XML with this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SupportedCultures></SupportedCultures>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 2):

You opened the "project.csproj.**user**" file. Be sure to open exactly "project.csproj" file.